# How to handle invalidated RealmList in RecyclerView

Tags: android-recyclerview, realm, realm-list

My Android app uses a `RecyclerView` to display a managed `RealmList` contained in a `RealmObject`. If the `RealmObject` is deleted I get the following error:

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Access to invalidated List object
> ```

The error occurs in the this section of the adapter (which extends `RecyclerView.Adapter`):

```java
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            if (mEventList != null) {
                return mEventList.size(); //Error occurs here
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        EventListAdapter(RealmList<TodoItem> todoItems, int colorGroup, OnStartDragListener dragStartListener) {
            this.mEventList = todoItems;
            this.colorGroup = colorGroup;
            this.mDragStartListener = dragStartListener;
        }
```

It occurs in conjunction with the following code to delete the `RealmObject` containing the `RealmList`. The error occurs before the Activity is closed and info is returned to its parent Activity

```java
   case R.id.navigation_delete:
        deleteGroup();
        sendIntentInfoBack(Constants.RESULT_CHANGED, createIntentBundle());
        return true;
```

```java
    private void deleteGroup() {
        mRealm.executeTransaction(realm -> {
            RealmList<TodoItem> eventsToDelete = mCurrentTodoList.getTodos();
            eventsToDelete.deleteAllFromRealm();
            RealmResults<TodoList> noteToDelete = mRealm.where(TodoList.class).equalTo(TodoList.PK, mCurrentTodoList.getPK()).findAll();
            noteToDelete.deleteAllFromRealm();
        });
    }
```

The user must be able to delete the `RealmObject` containing the `RealmList`.

### My Questions:

**How do I handle the `RealmList` being invalidated?** I've tried assigning the `RecyclerView` data source to be `null`, then doing `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter before deleting the `RealmObject`, but get the same error.
**Do I** disable the `RecyclerView`? If so, **how?**
**Do I** create an empty or throw-away `RealmList`, then assign a new adapter to the `RecyclerView` with this as the data source, then delete the `RealmObject`?
**Do I** close the `Activity` containing the `RecyclerView` and just handle deleting the `RealmObject` in the parent `Activity`?

Thanks for your consideration and time.